# Aerospike Spring Data Multiple Namespaces

Tags: spring-data

How can I configure multiple namespaces with same host list?

I am using

```
public class AerospikeConfiguration extends AbstractAerospikeDataConfiguration
```

Unlike hosts, I can only pass in one namespace name:

```
@Override
protected String nameSpace() {
    return app.getAerospikeNamespace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Starting at `spring-data-aerospike` version `3.1.0` there is support for multiple namespaces.
https://github.com/aerospike-community/spring-data-aerospike/releases/tag/3.1.0

You can also check out a multiple namespaces project example here:
https://github.com/aerospike-examples/spring-data-multiple-namespaces-example

---

There is no easy way to do this, providing the host list and a namespace creates an `AerospikeTemplate` @bean with a fixed name (that requires a single namespace).

If you try to create an additional configuration class with a different namespace your application won't start ("A bean with that name has already been defined in...").

I guess there is a way by extending `AerospikeDataConfigurationSupport` with your own class similar to `AbstractAerospikeDataConfiguration` and provide 2 AerospikeTemplates that matches the namespaces.

Is there a critical reason for using 2 namespaces in the same application? you should consider an [Aerospike set](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/data-model.html#sets) if your goal is to "separate" the data.

Comment: The namespaces are configured differently, mainly one can store bigger records than the other.  There is a set I need to read/write to in each namespace.